# API post call returns error but works on postman

Tags: angular, express

I have a working angular project which connects to the real data using webapi2. currently i'm working on an express.js project which mocks the data for demo purposes, so instead of consuming the real webapi2, i'll consume this express project which always shows random data. The angular project calls a post api which expects a json object. But the call always returns error. but when called using postman it is working.

code:

**angular component**

```
onSubmit(valid: boolean = false): void {
...
this.service.save(request).subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log(result,"RHAILHYDRA");
    ...
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error,"EHAILHYDRA");
    ...
  })
}
```

**angular service.ts**

```
public save(param: any): Observable < any > {
    let uri = "some url";
    let payLoad = {
        "someId": param.id,
        "someComment": param.comment
    };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'If-None-Match': param.tag
    });
    return this.http.post <any> (uri, payLoad, {
        headers: headers
    });
}
```

uri is always `http://localhost:44309/demo/5b42/trade?valid=false`

since its a mock, I didn't considered queries. so the api call will work with/without queries.

**express.js code**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
exports.register = function (app) {
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.post('/demo/:id/trade', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({
      "validationMessages": [],
      "overridable": true
    });
  });
};
```

When I click the submit button, it always goes to error "EHAILHYDRA".

[image]

but when I use postman, i'm getting expected result.

[image]

Any lead would be very helpful.

**UPDATE #1:**

When I click the submit, there's no call for this service in the inspect:network.

Comment: can you comment the `this.handleResponse(result)` in angular component i think there is an issue with the `handleResponse` method.

Comment: `this.handleResponse()` needed the json object returned from the post call. that's y the second error.

Comment: can you show me your `handleResponse method` and it would be great if you show your response

Comment: nothing wrong with `handleresponse method` it just need a json object which I'm not getting from the post call. see pic 1 for error and pic 2 for expected response. I can comment the handleresponse but still i'm getting error

Comment: Can you delete the `node_module` and install it again.

Comment: can please show the usage of `validationMessages `

Comment: @YashRami didn't worked.

Comment: @AbhishekMani when the service is called it always goes to error path (ie: EHAILHYDRA log).  `validationMessages` didn't caused it.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan Did you get `console.log(result);` if yes then error coming after the log

Comment: @YashRami yes. I'm getting error log for `console.log(error,"EHAILHYDRA");` not `console.log(result)`

Comment: @RanjithVaradan I just added an answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this issue comes when your header value is null or undefined. so remove header i mean `'If-None-Match': param.tag` part and try again.

---

```
public save(param: any): Observable < any > {
    let uri = "some url";
    let payLoad = {
        "someId": param.id,
        "someComment": param.comment
    };
   let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
    return this.http.post <any> (uri, payLoad, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but not working. man i'm this close to bash my head on this keyboard :(

Comment: @RanjithVaradan Can you show me your header section in network tab in your chrome inspect so i will get better idea what want wrong.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem, the call itself is not there in the network tab. but i'm getting the error in the console.

Comment: Maybe this issue comes when our header value is null or undefined. Okay lets do one thing remove header i mean `'If-None-Match': param.tag` part and try again let me know the end result.

Comment: COOL :) So problem with the header

Comment: :phew: please update the answer. i'll accept it. thanks again :) u r a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some `check` on `validationMessages`, whether it has some value or not.

Dont use the `validationMessages` directly.

There can be a case where `validationMessages` is undefined and you using that variable to call some predefined array functions.

Comment: I tried commenting `this.handleResponses` where the `validationMessages` is used. but still the service call itself returning to error path.